# Angular, Angular-ui : Date - Different ouput format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

My date is a string in this format:

```
Dec 31, 1969 7:00:00 PM
```

I want to show a shorter date on the view so i do this with angular

```
<input ui-date="{ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }" ui-date-format ng-model="project.date" />
```

But then project.date is no longer the old format but the unix one (I think) :

```
1969-12-09T05:00:00.000Z
```

But i want to ouptput it in the previous format :

```
Dec 31, 1969 7:00:00 PM
```

How could i do this?

Comment: not clear what format you want where. Create a live demo.

Comment: I want this one: Dec 31, 1969 7:00:00 PM I/O and just printed different on the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Date filter, exp : {{yourDate | date:'medium' }}
check this : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
<input ui-date="{ project.date | date : 'medium'}" ui-date-format ng-model="project.date" />
```

in you html tag or in your ctrl

```
$scope.today = $filter('date')(project.date,''MMM d, y h:mm:ss a'');
```

make sure you dependent inject `$filter` to your ctrl

[To see more of date formats here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3adate)